# Theorem 1.41 Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

After reading this theorem I have one question: Using theorem 1.27 we show that $$\int \limits_{X}gd\mu=(1)<\infty.$$ Also we must show that $g$ is measurable to conclude that $g\in L^1(\mu)$. Right?

Why $g$ is measurable? We know that pointwise limit of convergent measurable functions is measurable. Also we know that each $\chi_{E_i}$ is measurable since $E_i$ are measurable. But we don't know nothing about convergence?

Can anyone explain this moment please?

Comment: The indicators are nonnegative, so the partial sums are increasing and therefore have a (finite or infinite) limit., for each $x$.

Comment: @m7e, Thanks! when we talk about pointwise limit in measure theory. Let $f_n(x)$ are sequence of functions on $X$. When we say that $\lim f_n(x)$ exists for every $x\in X$ the limit $\infty$ also included? P.S. Sorry for my English :(

Comment: This is somewhat a matter of convention, but usually, yes.

Comment: @m7e, Thanks a lot!